# How to drag a button and autogenerate onclick method in Eclipse? How to find variable/method references in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a c# / visual Studio developer.  I'm porting some of my WP7 apps to Android and I have gotten pretty used to Eclipse.  I've read some "differences" documents but still have a couple burnning questions . . .

in VS I drag a button to the surface and assign a method name for onclick and it generates the method outline for me in my source file.  I can't see how to do this in Eclipse - can I?

in Vs if I put my cursor over a variable or method name I get a dropdown that has a "Go to" option and a "find all references" option.  these are really handy.  Can I do that in Eclipse?

Comment: In the future questions, please ask one question per Question (and invent a more smart title covering the concrete question). As to the references, rightclick variable/method and check the *References* option. Or put cursor on it and press Ctrl+Shift+G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're developing Android projects in Eclipse, so I will base my answers on that. I also guess you installed the Android Developer Pack plugin.

In the ADT plugin for Java, you can open a layout.xml and see its "Graphical Layout". You can drag UI components there, but it won't generate you code for handling events.

For the second question, in Eclipse you have to right-click on the variable or method and go to the "References" menu. Or you can learn the keyboard shortcuts and it becomes easier.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `onclick` and then pressing Ctrl+Space should open up a list of default functions you can override. Double-clicking or pressing Enter on one will bring it up in the editor (I usually type "on" before pressing Ctrl+Space, whenever I'm not sure about everything that can be done in a class.)

Right-clicking a variable will open up a context sensitive menu where you may view the variable's declaration (F3) or type hierarchy (F4); lower down the list is the References menu where you can view all the references to that variable in the workspace (Ctrl+Shift+G) or beyond.

You can also rename most variables by right clicking and choosing `Refactor > Rename...`, something I started using pretty early.